# Is the inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ an epimorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, epimorphisms

I have to prove this only in basic ring theory, I have read something in category theory, but its too complex for me at the moment.

The definition of epimorphism that I have is that the function can cancel other functions by the right side, i.e. let $f:X\to Y; g_1,g_2:Y\to Z$ if $g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f \Rightarrow g_1=g_2$.

By the point of the course, we have already proof that any homomorphism is a monomorphism if and only if it is injective.
Clearly, the inclusion function is mono (i.e. injective) but is not surjective.
I need to prove that it isn't an epimorphism either.

Comment: What is your definition of epimorphism? A surjective homomorphism? In that case the statement boils down to finding a rational number that is not an integer.

Comment: You mean that $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q $ is a ring epimorphism?

Comment: By the way, the standard terminology is "inclusion," and not "insertion"

Comment: I just edited the post with all of your comments, I think is better described now.

Comment: You cannot prove something that isn't true.

Answer (score 14):

The inclusion *is* an epimorphism, since if $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to R$ is a [unital ring morphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324/unital-homomorphism), and $a/b\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$f(a/b)=f(a)f(b^{-1})=f(a)f(b)^{-1}.$$

So $f$ is determined by its values on $\mathbb{Z}$, which is to say the inclusion $\iota\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is right-cancellative, since $f\circ\iota$ is effectively the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How is f(a/b) = f(a) * f(b^{-1})

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom It's because $\frac{a}{b}=a\cdot\frac{1}{b}=a\cdot b^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you mean the following.
The embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ is mono and epi in the category of rings, but it's clearly not an isomorphism.

Comment: No, I mean the inclusion function of all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ as a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @Armando Embedding and inclusion mean the same thing. Dietrich's point is that the function *is* an epimorphism.